# add superscript to \gls with index using hyperref package

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, superscripts, glossary

I want to add a superscript to a gls variable in the text.
The problem is, that the variable which I defined in the glossary comes with "curly-brackets" caused by the *hyperref* package.
Here is an minimal example to explain my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbols}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{scene_edge}
{
    name={\ensuremath{e_{scene}}},
    description={desc},
    sort=escene,
    type=symbolslist
}
\begin{document}
\printglossary
\printglossary[type=symbolslist]
\clearpage
\section{Test}
$\gls{scene_edge}$\\
$\gls{scene_edge}^{i}$\\ 
$e_{scene}^{i}$\\
${e_{scene}}^{i}$\\
\end{document}
```

and I want to call it in my tex file:

```
\gls{scene_edge}^{i}
```

What I want to have is something like:

```
$e_{scene}^{i}
```

What I actually get is:

```
${e_{scene}}^{i}
```

(Problem is that the index is very long and the superscript is added after that, and not like it should, right at the e)
The hyperref package creates a (red) box around the variable and prevents the superscript from fitting right on top of the variable.

I can achieve a wanted result by using \glsentrytext, but this removes hyperlinks.

Thanks for your help

Edit: Added hyperref as an issue

Image how the example looks like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Could you expand your code into an example we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue? You can always define a custom glossary macro to produce the output you need - along the lines of `\glspl` but, rather than a plural, it can be some other variant. By `brackets`, do you mean the curly ones in the input i.e. not something in the output?

Comment: I found out that the actual problem is the hyperref package in combination with the glossary package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be avoided using the advice on pages 166-167 of `glossaries`'s manual. The recommendation is to use the optional argument of `\gls`:

```
\gls{scene_edge}[^{i}]
```

[image: things in their places]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbols}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{scene_edge}
{
    name={\ensuremath{e_{scene}}},
    description={desc},
    sort=escene,
    type=symbolslist
}
\begin{document}
\printglossary
\printglossary[type=symbolslist]

\section{Test}

$\gls{scene_edge}$

\noindent$\gls{scene_edge}[^{i}]$

\noindent$e_{scene}^{i}$

\noindent${e_{scene}}^{i}$
\end{document}
```